# Starting files in other dirs using batch

Tags: batch-file

So, I'm trying to use a .bat file to start 3 other files (each in their own directory) all at the same time, but it only seems to start the first one. Here is what I have done

```
cd dir1
call bat1.bat
cd dir2
call bat2.bat
cd dir3
call exe1.exe
```

I'm assuming I may change to change the "call" function to something else

When i tried to run the code, it only started the first call. I believe that because all 3 of the calls start infinite loops, it is trying to wait until its done (it cant) so it doesn't start the other 2.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Turns out I wasn't using the correct syntax!

```
cd dir1
start bat1.bat
cd..
cd dir2
start bat2.bat
cd..
cd dir3
start exe1.exe
```

Comment: `cd..` is syntactically incorrect because of the missing space between the command `cd` (argument 0) and its first and only argument `..`. The command line `cd..` causes therefore a file system access by `cmd.exe` searching for a file with name `cd` in the current working directory. In most cases there is no file with such a name and then  the automatic correction of `cmd.exe` starts and finds out that meant is its internal command __CD__ with the argument `..` (parent directory).

Comment: If a parallel execution is wanted as it looks like, it would be better to use the following three command lines: __1.__ `start "Bat1" /D "%~dp0dir1" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C bat1.bat` __2.__ `start "Bat2" /D "%~dp0dir2" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C bat2.bat` __3.__ `start "Exe1" /D "%~dp0dir3" exe1.exe` Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and `start /?` and read the output usage helps. __START__ calls the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for an explanation of `%~dp0` which expands to full path of the batch file containing the three command lines always ending with a backslash, the directory separator on Windows as described by the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) explaining also the meaning of `.` and `..` and ``\`` at beginning of a file/folder name. The batch file with these three lines works even on current directory set by the parent process different to batch file directory.

Comment: There is one exception: If the batch file is stored on a network resource and executed with using the UNC path, the execution of `bat1.bat` and `bat2.bat` would fail because of `cmd.exe` itself changes the current working directory before starting the processing of the specified batch file. Solution: __1.__ `start "Bat1" /D "%~dp0dir1" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""%~dp0dir1\bat1.bat""` __2.__ `start "Bat2" /D "%~dp0dir2" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""%~dp0dir2\bat2.bat""` __3.__ `start "Exe1" /D "%~dp0dir3" "%~dp0dir3\exe1.exe"`